# If $H$ is a subgroup of $S_n$ contains transpositions $(1,2), (1,3), ..., (1,n)$ then $H = S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I have a question concerning permutations. 
I'm starter in group theory and would appreciate some ideas.
I read something about generators but I didn't understand very well how these work with permutations:

> Show if $H$ is a subgroup of $S_n$ contains transpositions $(1,2), (1,3), ..., (1,n)$ then $H = S_n$.

Comment: What have you tried? Suppose you were given all the transpositions, not just those $n-1$, could you do it then? If so, how do you construct the transposition $(a,b)$ from those given?

Comment: I know every permutation $\phi \in Sn$ can be writen like a product of transpositions and every transposition like that : $(ij) = (1i)(1j)(1i)$ but idk what to do with that.

Comment: Great! So you can see how to get all the transpositions. Can you see how to get the remaining permutations from the transpositions? How would you get $(1,2,3,4)$ for example?

Comment: I don't know...

Comment: If you don't know, how about searching this site for an understandable proof? I hope this will be helpful for you, in the future.

Comment: What is $(1,2,3,4)$ ?

Comment: @sticknycu  It is a **cycle**. It is the permutation which takes 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 4 and 4 to 1. Any pemutation can be written as a product of disjoint cycles - a fundamental and useful fact.

Comment: It's correct to say $(1,2,3,4) = (1,2)(3,4) $?

Comment: Hmm, what about if i show $S_n \subseteq H$ ? And then $H = S_n$. Hence $\forall \phi \in S_n$ can be writed as a transposition and every transposition like $(ij) = (1i)(1j)(1i)$ then we have $S_n \subseteq H$. Hence $H$ is subgroup of $S_n (H \subseteq S_n)$ we get $H = S_n$.

Comment: No, $(1234)$ is a $4$-cycle, but $(12)(34)$ is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see this, your observation that $(ij)=(1i)(1j)(1i)$ gives us every transposition.

But every element of $S_n$ can be written as a product of transpositions.  For instance,  $(abcdef)=(af)(ae)(ad)(ac)(ab)$.

Comment: Hardly useful! It is harder to prove the $(12)(12...n)$ result than to prove the transposition result from scratch!

Comment: @almagest You're right.  I edited.

Comment: Got it, thank you. I writed a comment.